# Incorrect output with infix code

Tags: java

I am stuck on this assignment. I am reading file and with each line I am running checkInfix static method. After the execution of checkInfix method, it should return the calculation of the infix line I am reading. For example, first one is 5*6+4 =34. if it does not then it should say"invalid". But, Output is wrong for this program for some lines as you see. 
my output is below....

---

5 * 6 + 4  <=this is correct because it print 34.

=34

3 - 2 +  <= correct answer

invalid

(3 * 4 - (2 + 5)) * 4 / 2 <=this one should print, 10 for answer but doesnt ..prints invalid

invalid

10 + 6 * 11 -(3 * 2 + 14) / 2 <=this one should print, 66 for answer but doesnt ..prints invalid

invalid

2 * (12 + (3 + 5 ) * 2   <= this is correct

invalid

invalid

---

Thank you so much for looking into it!!!
code::::>I did not post the main function because there was nothing in there. if you want I can post it if you want to see it.

```
public static int checkInfix(String inf)
{
    char[] c = inf.toCharArray();
    Stack<Integer> into = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Character>charo = new Stack<Character>();


    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
    {

        if (c[i] == ' ' || c[i]==',')
            continue;

        if (iOperand(c[i])){ // checking for operand 0 to 9
            StringBuffer z = new StringBuffer();
            while (i < c.length && c[i] >= '0' && c[i] <= '9')
                z.append(c[i++]);
            into.push(Integer.parseInt(z.toString()));
        }
        else if (c[i] == '(')
            charo.push(c[i]);

        else if (c[i] == ')')
        {
            while (!charo.empty()&& charo.peek() != '(')
                into.push(calucator(charo.pop(), into.pop(), into.pop()));
            charo.pop();
        }

        else if (iOperator(c[i])){ // checking for operator +,-,*,/
            while (!charo.empty() && HigerPreced(c[i],charo.peek()))
                into.push(calucator(charo.pop(), into.pop(), into.pop()));
            charo.push(c[i]);
        }
    }//end of for loop

    while (!charo.empty())
        into.push(calucator(charo.pop(), into.pop(), into.pop()));
    return into.pop();
}//end of checkinfix class



public static boolean iOperator(char C) {
    if (C == '+' || C == '-' || C == '*' || C == '/' || C == '%' )
        return  true;
    return false;
}
public static boolean iOperand(char C){
    if (C >= '0' && C<='9')
        return true;
    return false;
}
//check for precedence
public static boolean HigerPreced(char oprt1,char oprt2){
    if (oprt2 == ')' || oprt2 == '(' )return false;
    if ((oprt1 == '*'|| oprt1=='/')&&(oprt1=='+'||oprt1=='-'))return false;
    else
        return true;
}
//calculating
public static int calucator(char into, int oprnd1, int oprnd2)
{
    switch(into)
    {
    case '+': return oprnd1 + oprnd2;
    case '-': return oprnd1 - oprnd2;
    case '*': return oprnd1 * oprnd2;
    case '/': return oprnd1/oprnd2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2 * (12 + (3 + 5 ) * 2 <= this is correct, dont you think there is a close brace missing ? (First thoughts)

Comment: No because it is missing the first opening bracket that needs to be closed

Answer (score 0):

```
(oprt1 == '*'|| oprt1=='/')&&(oprt1=='+'||oprt1=='-')
```

`oprt2` should appear in this expression ... At present it can never be true.